# j2me - Rotate array of 2d points in 45 degree increments

Tags: java, graphics, java-me

I'm working on a roguelike style cellphone game that operates on a grid. Attacks/Items in this game operate by targeting tiles in a pattern relative to the user. The paturn is usually relative to the direction the user is aiming in as well,  For instance in this [screenshot](http://arlenphillips.googlepages.com/Shotgun.PNG) the pattern

```
Point2d[] damageTiles = new Point2d[4];

damageTiles[0] = new Point2d(0, -1);
damageTiles[1] = new Point2d(0, -2);
damageTiles[2] = new Point2d(1, -2);
damageTiles[3] = new Point2d(-1, -2);
```

is show relative to a temporary enemy(the yellow box) aiming "up".

I currently have simple code to rotate a pattern array by 90 degree increments, as seen [here](http://arlenphillips.googlepages.com/screenshot.2.png). My question is, Is there an easy way to rotate an array of 2d points by 45 degree increments, allowing my Attacks/Items to fire on the diagonal, preferably without using floating point math, as it tends to run slowly on many phones(or so i hear). This is probably a trivial question to anyone familiar with graphics programming, but I've been hit with a case of coder's-block.

My current rotation code is shown below. I now realize that a better way to do it would be to take an angle instead of a "direction" and rotate the points by that angle (rejecting angles that are not multiples of 45 of course).

```
private Point2d[] rotateList(Point2d[] points, int direction) {
    for (int i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {

        if (direction == ROTATE_LEFT) {
            int temp = points[i].x;
            points[i].x = points[i].y;
            points[i].y = -1 * temp;
        }
        else if (direction == ROTATE_RIGHT) {
            int temp = points[i].x;
            points[i].x = -1 * points[i].y;
            points[i].y = temp;
        }

    }

    return points;
}
```

Comment: This other question is similar (but not a duplicate) and might be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/484573/image-rotation-algorithm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The T-shaped attack you show would be difficult to rotate at 45 degrees--things don't really translate from 90 to 45.

```
original:
.....
.###.
..#..
..o..

alternative A:
.....
.##..
.##..
...o.

alternative B:
..#..
.#...
#.#..
...o.
```

There could easily be others for that pattern.

I recommend you create a 45 degree "Pattern" to match you 90 degree pattern, then rotate the 45degree pattern exactly the same way you rotate your 90 degree patterns.

Comment: I've just come to the same realization myself while trying out the rotation math in the other answers. I'll have to come up with a "diagonal" version of the patterns that need both, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a simple rotation matrix to rotate each point:
http://www.siggraph.org/education/materials/HyperGraph/modeling/mod_tran/2drota.htm

Answer (score 0):

sure, rotation counterclockwise in 2D (with positive x,y pointing to upper right) is just this (see [rotation matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix) in wikipedia)

```
[x']   [cos(theta)  -sin(theta)] [x]
[y'] = [sin(theta)   cos(theta)] [y]
```

for theta = 45 degrees, this becomes

```
 x' = 0.7071*x - 0.7071*y
 y' = 0.7071*x + 0.7071*y
```

(replace 0.7071 with sqrt(2)/2, I'm only using 4 digits here)